# Change library name on Cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I have a library available in CocoaPods, and I would like to change the case of its name.

Is there any way to do that? Or is the option to change the casing, push a new one and delete the old one?

Comment: better to ask it in their [mailing-list](http://groups.google.com/group/cocoapods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change the name of a podspec. Like you mentioned you could add a new one with a different case. You cannot/should not remove the old one so you don't break any user's projects. You can add the [`deprecated_in_favor_of`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#deprecated_in_favor_of) flag to the old one though. While that currently won't do much in the future that will be apparent in the UI.

**EDIT** based on comments:

1. This could break the users project if they don't check in their Pods (which I imagine many people don't) then they attempt to run `pod install`. In general we don't remove any specs unless their source has been removed.
2. I agree about the casing. This is something that has been discussed before. If you'd like to bring this up on the CocoaPods [issue tracker](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues) I think that's reasonable.

Comment: Thanks Keith! Two questions then:
1. Why would removing it break any user's projects? Wouldn't they still have their local version?
2. Why does case matter in the name of the library? I don't see the point of having any library with the same name but different case

Comment: Updated for your questions.